# how to add a .Net UWP C# project to a solution that has windows forms .net projects

Tags: .net, uwp

When I add my UWP C# project to a solution that contains windows forms projects, then the UWP project no longer builds and gets the errors below.

steps:
1. created win form VB project, which generated the solution
2. Added UWP project to the solution

I tried this with an empty win form project and solution, and then added UWP proj, and UWP proj fails to run.

I tried this with an empty UWP project and solution, and then added win form proj, and UWP proj  runs OK.

Is their a solution?

[image]

Comment: That's not a whole lot of information to go on, but you might try cleaning and rebuilding. You should also check the project build configurations associated with your solution build configurations.

Comment: What's your steps to add your UWP C# project? Basically the two projects are seperate and they shouldn't affect each other.

Comment: As long as the projects don't reference each other in any way, there should not be any conflict, please describe in more detail the steps you have performed